# What is the slope of a transfer function?

Tags: filters, finite-impulse-response, transfer-function, digital-filters, dsp-core

Lets say I have a Transfer function (H) plot as below. I need to find the SLOPE of the transfer function in dB/MHz.

[image: Digital LPF]

That is... i need a plot (db/MHz) vs frequency.

How can i go about it ?

```
f = 0: 1e6 : 80e6;
H_db=20*log10(abs(H));
s=diff(H_db);
plot(f/1e6,s);
```

Do i need steps of 1 Mhz .. then its in db/Mhz.. or do i need to divide `s` with something ?

or am i thinking about this all wrong ?

**(update)**

Lets say i have a transfer function below:

[image]

and then i find the db/mhz vs mhz plot using the following code:

```
step_size=1e6;
f_H = 0: step_size: fs_ADC+step_size;    % i am using 'f_H' and 'f' since with diff function in the end I am short of one index for ploting.. i hope this is correct
f = 0: step_size: fs_ADC;
H = fir1(f_H); 
H_db=20*log10(abs(H)); 
ss=diff(H_db);  % is this correct ?
plot(f/1e6,ss)
```

[image]

or should i use :

```
ss=diff(H_db)./diff(f_H);
plot(f/1e6,ss)
```

Then i get the below figure: .. now i get the 10^-5 on the yaxis.

[image]

Please let me know

Comment: Do you know how to find the slope (derivative) or any function? (Rise/Run....)

Comment: Hey Dan,  
Yeah a general slope formula slope = (diff(y)/diff(x) .. I have used before and its fine..
Its just i am confused about the db/mhz vs mhz  plot

Comment: So help me understand where you are confused. What if we substituted "MHz" in you x-axis to "x" and "dB" in your y-axis to "y" (So the starting plot would look the exact same with x going from 0 to 35 and y going from -120 to 0)? Then are you comfortable using the slope formula you gave? That answer of the slope would be y/x.  Substitute it back and its dB/MHz. Still confused? Or am I confused by your question?

Comment: Please check my updated post .. let me know ...
Thanks

Comment: Just think simply for each sample what is the difference in dB (from sample to sample) and divide that by what is the difference in MHz (from sample to sample).  Rise over Run. I see in your plot you divide you x-axis by 1e6 which tells me your raw data is actually in units of Hz. so diff(y)/diff(x) would give you dB/Hz, right?  If so if you want dB/MHz the multiply that by 1e6 Hz/MHz:      dB/Hz * 1e6 Hz/MHz  = dB/MHz. Make sense?

Comment: Thankyou very much Dan.. I think i got it now 
:) Cheers !

Comment: Post your own answer

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I think i got it after some clarification from Dan. Thanks Dan. !

I think what i was confused with was the step size in my frequency vector.. i had thought to have the final result in db/mhz.. the steps should be in 1 Mhz.. but i now realize that the freq vector could be in whatever steps i like but if its in Hz then i need to have my final answer normalized by 1e6 to get from  db/Hz --> db/Mhz

So this is the code i finally used..

```
fs_ADC=200e6;
N=2^11;
step_size=fs_ADC / N ;
f = 0: step_size: fs_ADC;
H = fir1(f);  
H_db=20*log10(abs(H));
slope=1e6*diff(H_db)./diff(f);  % db/Hz--> db/mhz
plot(f(1:end-1)/1e6,slope)
```

Figure result till 30 MHz is shown below:

[image]